# Trying to find the sum of individual columns

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have to open this data file in matlab:

- A   12   E  88
- B   23   F  22
- C   55   G  77
- D   66   H  44

I named it Thor.dat and this is my code in matlab

```
    fid = fopen('Thor.dat')

if fid == -1
    disp ('File open not successful')
else
    disp ('File open is successful')

mat = textscan(fid,'%c %f %c %f')

[r c] = size(mat)

matcolsum

fclose(fid)
end
```

This is the function I am using to add the numerical columns:

```
    function outsum = matcolsum(mat)
 % matcolsum finds the sum of every column in a matrix
 % Returns a vector of the column sums
 % Format: matcolsum(matrix)

 [row, col] = size(mat);

 % Preallocate the vector to the number of columns 
 outsum = zeros(1,col);

 % Every column is being summed so the outer loop 
 % has to be over the columns
  for i = 1:col
  % Initialize the running sum to 0 for every column
  runsum = 0;
  for j = 1:row
      runsum = runsum + mat(j,i);
  end
  outsum(i) = runsum;
end
end
```

When I run the code, it keeps on giving me this error: Input argument 'mat' is undefined. Could anyone please help me out? I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: i and j are used by matlab it's not recommended to use them as loop counters.

Comment: Be aware the the output of `textscan` is a cell array (here `mat`) so you need to access data inside with curly braces {}.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your expected output is, here. Are you trying to sum... character codes? An example of the intended result would help immensely.

Comment: Hi. I am only trying to sum the numerical columns. The only example I found was this:
    `mat = [3:5; 2 5 7]
      mat = 3   4   5
              2   5   7

so matcolsum should return:
ans = 5  9  12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, according to your comment, what you want is the sum of numerical (aka even-numbered, in your example) columns, your code can be turned into this (I swapped row and column iteration for clarity):

```
function outsum = matcolsum(mat)
 % matcolsum finds the sum of every column in a matrix
 % Returns a vector of the column sums
 % Format: matcolsum(matrix)

 [row, col] = size(mat);
 outsum = zeros(1,col);

 for i = 1:row
    for j = 2:2:col
      outsum(j) = outsum(j) + mat(i,j);
    end
  end
end
```

This works for me (in Octave, I don't have a machine with MATLAB at hand), and results in

```
ans =

     0   167     0   231
```

If I misread your comment and you actually want to sum *all* the columns just replace `2:2:col` with `1:col`.

**However**, this is kind of un-MATLAB-like.
MATLAB can better manipulate vectors and matrices with higher level vector functions, which is best if you want to fully exploit your hardware (especially parallelism).

**You can thus simply write:**

```
mat = ["A", 23, "E", 88; 
       "B", 23, "F", 22; 
       "C", 55, "G", 77; 
       "D", 66, "H", 44]

[row, col] = size(mat);
sum(mat(:,2:2:col))
```

Resulting in

```
ans =

   167   231
```

The meaning should be self-evident once you know that `mat(:,i)` is the i-th column of the matrix `mat` and that `a:i:b` is the numbers `{a, a+i, a+2i, ...}`

If you are used to C-style `for` loops it can take a while to deprogram your brain from thinking about iterating explicitly over an array.

Comment: Thanks. I think your method works. it just I have the matrix in a cell array so it keeps on giving me this error: ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.

Any idea what this means?

Comment: You may want to use http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html to convert your cell array to an ordinary matrix.

Comment: cell2mat is for cell arrays with the same data type :(

Comment: Well, this is kind of awkward, but `cell = {{"A", 23, "E", 88},{"B",23,"F",22},{"C",55,"G",77},{"D",66,"H",44}};  mat=transpose([cellfun((@(x)x{1,2}), cell); cellfun((@(x)x{1,4}), cell)])` works for me